# Фразеологізм "витрішки продавати" - значення та вживання

Tags: фразеологізми

Цей фразеологізм зустрівся меня в творі Івана Котляревського "Наталка Полтавка"

> Виборний. Та що його питати: він по городу гав ловив та витрішки продавав…

Через незнайомий вислів значення речення було не надто зрозумілим. Та вислів сподобався і хотілося б ним прикрашати свою мову.

Значення вислову було знайдено: Витрішки купувати (продавати) — заглядати без діла, роздивлятися безцільно. Витрішки продавати — ледарювати.

Хотілося б дізнатися про доречне застосування фразеологізму в повсякденному мовленні.

Сподіваюся на допомогу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тлумачення даного фразеологізму є у [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/vytrishky):

> Витрішки продавати (купувати, ловити, їсти і т. ін.) — нічого не
>   роблячи, дивитися, роздивлятися навкруги. — А я більше не піду до їх
>   сидіти в кутку та витрішки продавати, — сказала писарша
>   (Нечуй-Левицький, IV, 1956, 137); І пішов [Пархім] по базару витрішків
>   їсти (Квітка-Основ'яненко, II, 1956, 476); — Навіщо нам туди йти?
>   Витрішки купувати я не хочу (Василь Кучер, Прощай.., 1957, 11)

Також  у [фразеологічному словнику](http://svitslova.com/idioms-dictionary/2210-vytrishky-prodavaty.html) знаходимо аналогічне тлумачення:

> Витрішки продавати - ледарювати.
>   Виборний. Та що його питати: він по
>   городу гав ловив та витрішки продавав... (Котляревський, Твори, т. II,
>   1953, стор. 28).

Також однаковими за значенням до цього фразеологізму є: [витрішки купувати](http://svitslova.com/idioms-dictionary/2211-vytrishky-kupuvaty.html) та [витрішки ловити](http://svitslova.com/idioms-dictionary/2212-vytrishky-lvyty.html).

> Витрішків купувати - гуляти без мети.
>   А за ділом же вони (дівчата) й вийшли? А як же? Витрішків купувати, та щоб чи не пожартують парубки з ними (Квітка-Основ'яненко, Твори, т. II, 1956, стор. 17).
>
> Витрішки ловити - вештатися без мети.
>   В другій чверті й мух не стало, - не зівав, 
>   Цілу чверть ловив наш Петя в класі гав. 
>   В третій – майже й на уроки не ходив, 
>   Бо на вулиці він витрішки ловив 
>   (Білоус, Зигзаг, 1956, стор. 72).

СУМ також подає, як синонім *витрішки їсти*, а у [фразеологічному словнику](http://svitslova.com/idioms-dictionary/2209-vytrishky-jisty.html) цей вираз має таке значення:

> Витрішки їсти в ролі прис; вульг.– дивитися на кого-, що-небудь з надмірною цікавістю.
>   І пішов (Пархім) по базару витрішків їсти (Квітка-Основ'яненко, Твори, т. II, 1956, стор. 476).